# What does "local" mean?

Tags: graphs, terminology

I study graph theory on my own using Diestel's *Graph Theory* book (with Algorithmic graph theory in mind). I don't understand what *local property*, *global property*, *locality* mean given a graph $G$.

For example, on the page 5 it says

> The average degree quantifies globally what is measured **locally** by the
>   vertex degrees: the number of edges of $G$ per vertex. Sometimes it will
>   be convenient to express this ratio directly, as $\varepsilon(G) := |E|/|V|$.

In particular, I found the following phrases including the word *local...*

- *local information* (pg. 46)
- *maximum local density* (pg. 61)
- *the above local structures* (pg. 101)
- *locally looks like a tree* (pg. 110)
- *there is a local reason for it* (pg. 110)
- *we are looking for local implications of global assumptions* (pg. 181).

and many more...

Could someone explain (possibly with examples) what these *local* and *global* mean in the context of the graph theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Local property** - a property that relates to a specific vertex and its near neighbors. For example, the number of neighbors or 2nd order neighbors a vertex $v$ has. "*locally looks like a tree*" more formally could be written as the sub-graph of vertices with distance $k$ or less of the vertex $v$ is a tree.

**Global property** - a property that relates to the graph, like its diameter, average degree, number of connected components or even its size.

Comment: $\Upsilon(G) = \max_{n>1}{\left[ \frac{m_n}{n-1}\right] }$, where $m_n$ is the maximum number of edges of a sub-graph on $n$ vertices. This number is defined as the *arboricity* of the graph $G$. This book says that "the arboricity is a measure for the maximum local density". So, $\Upsilon(G)$ is a property of a graph rather than just a single vertex. I guess by "local" it means the property of a whole sub-graph rather than a single vertex and its neighbourhood. Any idea?

Comment: $\Upsilon(G)$ is in some sense a global property.

Comment: This is not well defined, but IMO a property of a sub-graph of size n is a (borderline) local property, but a property that involves the maximal over all sub-graphs of size n is global. Arboricity is a global property.

Comment: What is not well-defined? $\Upsilon(G)$ or arboricity? $\Upsilon(G)$ is defined [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arboricity.html) and in HARARY's Graph theory book. It's also defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboricity). Diestel writes "the arboricity is a measure for the maximum local density".

Comment: I meant the distinction between local and global is not well defined. For example one could say a property of a sub-graph is global if the sub-graph size is large enough relative to the graph.